# Server upload en nodejs

Tags: nodejs, apache, nginx, servidor, upload

una consulta , como haría para hacer un server upload en nodejs , con un balanceador de carga como nginx ?.

Les pongo este escenario.

Server A , Server B , los 2 con la misma app corriendo en un puerto , y balanceandolo con nginx,por ejemplo tengo un formulario el cual va a subir fotos y diferentes archivos ,así como algunos datos,cuanto estos se guardan , se guardan en una carpeta /upload respecto al server donde se ha hecho la solicitud,luego como en la bd trabajo con urls , no hay problema en traer todos los datos,sin embargo mi consulta va mas a la parte de es escalable hacerlo de esa forma ? , pues yo quiero almacenar todos los uploads de los x servidores que tenga en 1 solo server dedicado solo a ello , y servirlo como archivos estaticos luego , sin embargo todo ese trayecto desde el server x al server upload , no estoy seguro como realizarlo , usar ssh dentro de node , para mover los archivos?  , o como lo realizarían ustedes.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer que los servidores que no estén destinados al upload monten una carpeta del servidor de uploads usando NFS. De esta manera todos los archivos subidos a cualquier servidor en realidad se guardan en el servidor de uploads.

NFS tiene sus desventajas también. En particular, la escritura a disco sobre una carpeta NFS tendrá más latencia y menor velocidad que escribir en un disco físco de la máquina.